# Execute function on all possible combinations of parameters

Tags: python, function, combinations

I have sets of values that I want to apply as parameters to a function:

```
params = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [5, 6, 7],
    'x': [None, 'eleven', 'f'],
    # et cetera
}
```

I want to run `myfunc()` with all possible combinations, so `myfunc(a=1, b=5, x=None ...)`, `myfunc(a=2, b=5, x=None ...)` ... `myfunc(a=3, b=7, x='f' ...)`. Is there something (for example in `itertools`) that can help? I thought about using `itertools.product()` but that doesn't keep the names of the parameters and just gives me tuples of the combinations.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to get all combinations of arguments:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for xs in itertools.product([1,2], [5,6], ['eleven', 'f']):
...     print(xs)
... 
(1, 5, 'eleven')
(1, 5, 'f')
(1, 6, 'eleven')
(1, 6, 'f')
(2, 5, 'eleven')
(2, 5, 'f')
(2, 6, 'eleven')
(2, 6, 'f')
```

With [Argument list unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), you can call `myfunc` with all combinations of keyword arguments:

```
params = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3],
    'b': [5, 6, 7],
    'x': [None, 'eleven', 'f'],
}

def myfunc(**args):
    print(args)

import itertools
keys = list(params)
for values in itertools.product(*map(params.get, keys)):
    myfunc(**dict(zip(keys, values)))
```

output:

```
{'a': 1, 'x': None, 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'x': None, 'b': 6}
{'a': 1, 'x': None, 'b': 7}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'eleven', 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'eleven', 'b': 6}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'eleven', 'b': 7}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'f', 'b': 5}
...
```

Comment: That's very neat! I'm concerned about the order being off though, since dicts are unordered (right?). That could mean that `itertools.product()` returns the parameters in a different order than you have the keys, which would lead to a mismatch.

Comment: @Bluefire, `myfunc(a=1, b=2, c=3)` , `myfunc(b=2, c=3, a=1)` both okay.

Comment: `map(params.get, keys)` is a needlessly verbose way of writing `params.values()` here; it's guaranteed that `.keys()` and `.values()` will align unless the dictionary is modified.

Comment: @falsetru I understand that, my concern is a mismatch where you pass the value of `a` into `b` and vice versa.

Comment: @DSM, I couldn't be sure. Also I wanted the code works both for Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: @Bluefire, That's why I separated `keys = list(params)` and get values by using `map(params.get, keys)` (to match keys orders with values orders)

Comment: @falsetru: nothing you're doing behaves differently between 2 and 3.

Comment: @Bluefire, I could go agressive (?) like other answer or DSM's comment. But I'm not sure whether it's guaranteed or just CPython implementation details.

Comment: @DSM, My fault. I thought `dict.keys()` in Python 3.x returns a kind of iterator which is consumed once it's being iterated.

Answer (score 5):

Ordering of `.keys` and `.values` are **guaranteed** across all Python versions (unless dict is altered which does not happen here), so this might be a bit trivial:

```
from itertools import product

for vals in product(*params.values()):
    myfunc(**dict(zip(params, vals)))
```

You can find the gurantee in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> If keys, values and items views are iterated over with no intervening
>   modifications to the dictionary, the order of items will directly
>   correspond.

---

**Demo**:

```
for vals in product(*params.values()):
    print(dict(zip(params, vals)))
```

---

```
{'a': 1, 'x': None, 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'x': None, 'b': 6}
{'a': 1, 'x': None, 'b': 7}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'eleven', 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'eleven', 'b': 6}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'eleven', 'b': 7}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'f', 'b': 5}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'f', 'b': 6}
{'a': 1, 'x': 'f', 'b': 7}
...
```

Comment: Maybe add a link to the [guarantee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects)?

Comment: @DSM Yes sir, included. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I developed [combu](https://github.com/takelushi/combu) which is that solution.

1. Install combu

> pip install combu

2. Use combu

```py
# Case 1: Directly call
import combu

for res, param in combu.execute(myfunc, params):
    print(res, params)

# Case 2: Use class
from combu import Combu

comb = Combu(myfunc)

for res, param in comb.execute(params):
    print(res, params)
```